# How to reuse html bloc (with props.state in it) in the most effective way in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have repeated code in my solution that I would like to put in one single place. My problem is that in the html bloc, I have a toggle logic that calls a method (handleClick) to change the state and when I put the html bloc into that function, it says that **handleClick is not defined in the reuseHtml() function.** Maybe I dont understand how the scope works and what I can call depending of where I am in the code. [image]

### Code with reused html blocs (that dosen't tworks) :

I have this error : **TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined**

```
handleClick() {
        console.log(this.state.showAllElmts)
        this.setState( {
            showAllElmts : !this.state.showAllElmts
        })
    }


render() {

        const allElmts = [
            {id: "1", label: "1", value: 1},
            {id: "2", label: "2", value: 3},
            {id: "3", label: "3", value: 3},
           
        ];

        let elmtsArray = <component options={allElmts}/>

        const num = 3;  

        function reuseHtml(param) {
            return <div>
                        <OptionBoutonTouch options={param}/>
                        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.showAllButtons ? "less" : "more"}</button>
                   </div>

        }

        if (num < elmtsArray.length)
        {
            if (!this.state.showAllElmts) {

                const specificElmts = allButtons.slice(0, nbEntree);
                elmtsArray = reuseHtml(specificElmts) 
                 
            }
            if (this.state.showAllButtons) {

                elmtsArray = reuseHtml(allElmts) 
            }

        }

        return (
            <div>
                {elmtsArray }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

### solution with repeted code that I started from :

```
handleClick() {
        console.log(this.state.showAllElmts)
        this.setState( {
            showAllElmts : !this.state.showAllElmts
        })
    }


render() {

        const allElmts = [
            {id: "1", label: "1", value: 1},
            {id: "2", label: "2", value: 3},
            {id: "3", label: "3", value: 3},
           
        ];

        let elmtsArray = <component options={allElmts}/>

        const num = 3;  

        if (num < elmtsArray.length)
        {
            if (!this.state.showAllElmts) {
                const specificElmts = allButtons.slice(0, nbEntree);
                elmtsArray =
                    <div>
                        <OptionBoutonTouch options={specificElmts}/>
                        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.showAllElmts ? "less" : "more"}</button>
                    </div>
            }
            if (this.state.showAllButtons) {
                elmtsArray =
                    <div>
                        <OptionBoutonTouch options={allButtons}/>
                        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.showAllElmts ? "less" : "more"}</button>
                    </div>
            }

        }

        return (
            <div>
                {elmtsArray }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword is a reference to the function scope, in your case `reuseHtml` and it doesn't contain `handleClick` function on it.
You can pass it as a parameter in `reuseHtml`.

```
function reuseHtml(param, handleClick){
  return <div><button onClick={handleClick}></button></div>
}
```

Something like this

Comment: Hey :) It works, but now the problem is with this.state.showAllElmts. How can I solve it? thanks

Comment: It depends, you could pass it the same way you do with `handleClick`, however I think you must organize your code structure making all that functions visible in your `reuseHtml`